# Saving an object from Grails controller fails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

There is a controller just updating an object:

```
def obj = Table.find(...)
obj.state = "END"
if(!obj.save(flush:true)) ...
// Session flushing does not help too.
// I am able to fetch that object again here but it is never persisted to DB
```

When deployed onto a Debian, **the object is not actually persisted** although there is no any errors reported (nor by manual checking nor by `failOnError`). But if deployed onto my local Windows machine the object is persisted correctly. The both machines are connected to the same DB.

Moving the `save` into a service or covering it `withTransaction` are workarounds. Yes, I know services are a better place to deal with DB. Instead I'm interesting to find what is the cause of such inconsistent and problematic behavior (and how to fix it in a single place). Or it is prohibited by design doing such things in controllers?

Grails 2.1.1, Tomcat

Excerptions from `DataSource.groovy`:

```
dataSource {
  driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  pooled = true
}
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = false
  cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

Comment: You can save object into DB without problems. Check into DataSource.groovy if your production datasource configuration is ok. On your local machine probably you are using development configuration, on deployed app you are using production

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is no validation errors.

```
obj.validate()
obj.errors.each {

  if(obj.hasErrors)
  println it
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned already, there is no errors on save that could be caught in runtime.